# listview('refresh') in JQuery seems not working

Tags: android, jquery, listview, cordova

I'm developing an app for Android using Phonegap and JQuery. One of the tasks is to dynamically add some content to the list. In the first time, when I add a first element and call .listview() everything seems to be fine, but when I add some content, its styles doesn't work properly, and listview('refresh') and other commands don't help at all. I'm using jquery mobile 1.0a1. Here is the code for two buttons:

```
    $("#nextDay").click(function(){ 
$("#SheduleList").append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">ololo1</h3></a></li>');
$('#SheduleList').listview('refresh');  
});

$("#prevDay").click(function(){
$("#SheduleList").append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">ololo</h3></a></li>');
$("#SheduleList").listview();   
});
```

The first Button is "prevButton". Here is some HTML:

```
<body onload="init();">
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>Расписание группы 04-322</h1>
<h1 id=hday>День недели</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
<ul id="SheduleList"> 
</ul>
<button id="nextDay">Следующий день</button>
<button id="prevDay">Предыдущий день</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone.
This seems to work the best for me:

```
refresh = function (selector)
{
 try
 {            
 //this may throw an exception: 
 //  call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
 $(selector).listview('refresh'); 
 }
 catch (e) 
 {
 }
}

refresh("#SheduleList");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-role="listview"` in your `<ul>` in HTML.

```
<ul id="SheduleList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
```